# ActiveMQ Web console using LDAP Active Directory authentication

Tags: activemq-classic

Struggling to get ActiveMQ web console to use LDAP and authenticated against Active Directory. 
No errors when starting MQ, username/password login box prompt appears but doesn't progress when inserting the correct credentials.

**Version**
5.15.6

**login.config**

```html
amqLdapLoginModule {
   org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.spi.LdapLoginModule required
   debug="true"
   contextFactory="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
   hostname="ad-server1.domain.com"
   port="389"
   bindDn="CN=readonly-user,OU=Accounts,DC=domain,DC=com"
   bindPassword="readonly-user-password"
   authenticationMethod="simple"
   forceBindingLogin="false"
   userBaseDn="CN=users,DC=domain,DC=com"
   userRdnAttribute="uid"
   userIdAttribute="uid"
   userPasswordAttribute="userPassword"
   userObjectClass="inetOrgPerson"
   roleBaseDn="CN=groups,DC=domain,dc=com"
   roleNameAttribute="cn"
   roleMemberAttribute="uniqueMember"
   roleObjectClass="groupOfUniqueNames";
   };
```

**jetty.xml**

```html
    <bean id="ldapLoginService" class="org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.JAASLoginService">
        <property name="name" value="LdapRealm" />
        <property name="loginModuleName" value="amqLdapLoginModule" />
        <property name="roleClassNames" value="org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.JAASRole" />
        <property name="identityService" ref="identityService" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="identityService" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.DefaultIdentityService"/>

    <bean id="securityConstraint" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Constraint">
        <property name="name" value="BASIC" />
        <property name="roles" value="admins-group" />
        <!-- set authenticate=false to disable login -->
        <property name="authenticate" value="true" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="adminSecurityConstraint" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Constraint">
        <property name="name" value="BASIC" />
        <property name="roles" value="admins-group" />
         <!-- set authenticate=false to disable login -->
        <property name="authenticate" value="true" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="securityHandlerLdap" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler">
        <property name="loginService" ref="ldapLoginService" />
        <property name="identityService" ref="identityService" />
        <property name="realmName" value="LdapRealm" />
        <property name="authenticator">
            <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.BasicAuthenticator" />
        </property>
        <property name="constraintMappings">
            <list>
                <ref bean="adminSecurityConstraintMapping" />
                <ref bean="securityConstraintMapping" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="handler" ref="secHandlerCollection" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection">
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the guide from http://bacedifo.blogspot.com/2013/06/securing-activemq-580-web-console-using.html and using the ldaptive ldap java library with some tweaks to the configs I managed to get this working for our AD environment.

Copied the ldaptive-{version number}.jar and jetty-jass-{version number}.jar to /activemq/lib directory.

**login.conf**

```
activemq {
    org.ldaptive.jaas.LdapLoginModule required
        debug=true
        storePass="true"
        ldapUrl="ldap://ldap-server1.domainname.com:389 ldap://ldap-server2.domainname.com:389"
        connectionStrategy="ACTIVE_PASSIVE"
        bindDn="CN=ldap-readaccount,OU=Read Accounts,DC=domainname,DC=com"
        baseDn="OU=accounts,DC=domainname,DC=com"
        bindCredential="ldapuser-password"
        useStartTLS="false"
        userFilter="(sAMAccountName={user})";

    org.ldaptive.jaas.LdapRoleAuthorizationModule required
        useFirstPass="true"
        ldapUrl="ldap://ldap-server1.domainname.com:389 ldap://ldap-server2.domainname.com:389"
        connectionStrategy="ACTIVE_PASSIVE"
        bindDn="CN=ldap-readaccount,OU=Read Accounts,DC=domainname,DC=com"
        baseDn="OU=groups,DC=domainname,DC=com"
        bindCredential="ldapuser-password"
        roleFilter="(&(cn=webconsoleadmins)(member={user}))"
        useStartTLS="false"
        defaultRole="admins"
        roleAttribute="cn";
```

};

**jetty.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="securityLoginService" class="org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.JAASLoginService">
    <property name="name" value="LdapRealm" />
    <property name="loginModuleName" value="activemq" />
    <property name="roleClassNames" value="org.ldaptive.jaas.LdapRole" />
    <property name="identityService" ref="identityService" />
</bean>
<bean id="identityService" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.DefaultIdentityService"/>


<bean id="securityConstraint" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Constraint">
    <property name="name" value="BASIC" />
    <property name="roles" value="admins,webconsoleadmins" />
    <!-- set authenticate=false to disable login -->
    <property name="authenticate" value="true" />
</bean>
<bean id="adminSecurityConstraint" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Constraint">
    <property name="name" value="BASIC" />
    <property name="roles" value="admins,webconsoleadmins" />
     <!-- set authenticate=false to disable login -->
    <property name="authenticate" value="true" />
</bean>
```

...

```
<bean id="securityHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler">
    <property name="loginService" ref="securityLoginService" />
    <property name="identityService" ref="identityService" />
    <property name="authenticator">
        <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.BasicAuthenticator" />
    </property>
    <property name="constraintMappings">
        <list>
            <ref bean="adminSecurityConstraintMapping" />
            <ref bean="securityConstraintMapping" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="handler" ref="secHandlerCollection" />
</bean>
```